# Debugging is Very Slow Via F10

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2008.In aspx page When stepping through my C# code line by line via F10, it takes the debugger over one second to get to the next line.
I've tried deleting all breakpoints, but that did not make any difference.

If any one Know about this tell me.

Regards

Nanda Kishore.CH

Comment: This could be related to any number of things outside of Visual Studio, ie. speed of your machine, amount of ram, other programs running in the background. Also the speed of the debugger is affected by the operations being performed on each line. I'm used to a slow debugger but I couldn't live without it!

Comment: How fast or slow is VS2008 when you are doing other activities - is editing or compiling your code also slow or just debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable logging function in your project, if you use logging framework